# A problem with cin after a getline makes my while loop never end at the second iteration in c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, buffer, getline

If I replace the getline for a cin, just as a test, it works as I want. But the moment I introduce the getline it creates a never-ending loop at the second iteration. I think it has something to be with the buffer but I don't know how it works so I need help.

This is the code:

```
while(true)
 {
      alumno++;
     cout<<"Alumno "<<alumno<<":"<<endl;
     getline(cin,nombre_alumno);
     if(nombre_alumno == "EXIT")break;

     cin>>nota;

 }
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with debugger? Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this statement

```
cin>>nota;
```

insert

```
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

You will need to include the header

```
#include <limits>
```